# Blazor component as partial class doesn't see implemented interface method from inside its view

Tags: c#, blazor, interface-implementation

I have a Blazor component with a separate code behind file as a partial class, not component base class. This class inherits from MyComponentBase and implements IMyInterface:

```
public interface IMyInterface { Task Export(); }

public partial class TableComponent<TRow, TTable> : 
    MyComponentBase<TableModel<TTable>>, IMyInterface
    where TRow : DataRow
    where TTable : TypedTableBase<TRow>
{
    public async Task Export() {}
}
```

I want to call the implemented method Export from the component's view. It works in the second button only (see code below) - with explicit conversion to the interface. For the first case it says that **"Export" method doesn't exist in the current context**:

```
@inherits MyComponentBase<TableModel<TTable>>
@typeparam TRow where TRow : DataRow
@typeparam TTable where TTable : TypedTableBase<TRow>
@*@implements IMyInterface*@@*throws doesn't implement IMyInterface*@

<button @onclick="@(() => Export())"/>Export</button>    
<button @onclick="@(() => ((IMyInterface)this).Export())"/>Export</button>
```

Why can't I just call the Export method without conversion? Something wrong with syntax in the view? I'm not sure whether I made it right - perhaps it requires additional

```
@implements IMyInterface
```

under type parameters in the view. But in this case it says that my component doesn't implement IMyInterface.

**Update:** added "[member name] doesn't exist in the current context" error message from the compiler when using the Export without casting to interface.

Comment: Remove all the specifiers from the code file, just:  `partial class TableComponent<TRow, TTable> { ... }` and do add the `@implements` to the view. See how that goes.

Comment: @HH The issue was in another place, then inheritance, interface or type parameters syntax, but this approach - to simplify the code as much as possible and then trying to add complexity step by step - helped me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, my explanation in the original post was not so clear, because I didn't understand my situation well. But the issue laid in such a trivial place. **I just used another component from another folder structure as a base for my new component, but forgot to adjust the namespace according to the new folder structure, where I placed this my new component.**

So, a little history of my investigations. As I mentioned later while trying to find the issue and simplified the component to just a single string field, even this field were not seen from the view - I received error message like "[member name] doesn't exist in the current context" - and that was very strange. Tried to relocate the whole component (razor and razor.cs files) to another folder with cut-paste within the Solution Explorer, and Visual Studio corrected the namespaces. And only after that all worked well. Then I tried to get the component back to its original location - again with the help of Visual Studio - and all worked fine again. Then I guessed that the issue lies in the namespace names, as [MrC aka Shaun Curtis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13065781/mrc-aka-shaun-curtis) said in his answer. Just adjusting the namespace in my original component (with the whole, unsimplified code) removed all errors as well as in my simplified component.

It doesn't require

```
@implements IMyInterface
```

in the view. And

```
((IMyInterface)this).Export()
```

will not work, because it leads to the interface implementation, not to the implementation in my component class.

Answer (score 1):

It should all work.

The *throws doesn't implement IMyInterface* suggests that `TableComponent.razor` and `TableComponent.razor,cs` aren't being linked properly - maybe a namespace problem?

Here's a simplified version of your code (I think) that demonstrates interfaces working as expected.

```cs
public interface IMyComponent
{
    public void Execute();
}
```

*MyComponent.razor*

```cs
@implements IMyComponent
<h3>MyComponent</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.Execute >Click</button>
```

*MyComponent.razor.cs*

```cs
public partial class MyComponent : ComponentBase, IMyComponent
{
    protected string? message;
    public void Execute()
    {
        message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
```

*Index.razor*

```cs
@page "/"
@inherits MyComponent

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="alert alert-info">@this.message</div>
```

*Index.razor.cs*

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace SO75750129.Pages;

public partial class Index : MyComponent
{
}
```

Comment: "maybe a namespace problem?" - That is it! Added an update to my original post that clears a little, what had happend. So, I just used another component from another folder structure as a base for my new component, but forgot to adjust the namespace.